# Getting ruby related errors while executing puppet -V after puppet client installation

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, puppet

I am trying to install puppet on ubuntu client. 
I have executed following steps:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev ruby-dev
echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian_stable.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libaugeas-ruby1.9.1 augeas-tools
sudo apt-get install puppet
```

I am getting this error:

```
@ubuntu:~$ puppet -V
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml/syck_node_monkeypatch.rb:42:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Syck (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml.rb:197:in `<module:YAML>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml.rb:132:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/vendor/require_vendored.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/vendor.rb:40:in `require_libs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/vendor.rb:53:in `load_vendored'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:174:in `<module:Puppet>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/puppet:7:in `<main>'
```

It will be great to point out if I missed anything here.

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/system_requirements.html#ruby

Comment: How can I install puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb v3.8 of puppet? Did I miss any command?

Comment: Well I'm not 100% sure which version you have installed at the moment. I might be wrong. `apt-cache policy puppet` would perhaps tell you which one you have.

Comment: Which OS are you running exactly? Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have Ruby 2.3.0, so you've either changed it or you're actually on 16.04. (In which case, use Xenial packages, not Trusty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No version of Puppet supports Ruby 2.2+ at the moment. Even the latest version of Puppet (v4.8) does not support 2.2+:

> **System Requirements**
>
> Ruby
>   Use one of the following versions of MRI (standard) Ruby:
>
> 2.1.x
>   2.0.x
>   1.9.3
>
> *Note: We currently only test and package with 2.1.x versions of Ruby, therefore we recommend you only use this version. Other interpreters and versions of Ruby are not covered by our tests.*

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/system_requirements.html#ruby

**Solution**:
Downgrade to Ruby 2.1.

**Alternative Solution**:
A solution proposed here to work around the YAML Syck/Psych issue:
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3796

Add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'safe_yaml', '~> 1.0.4'
```

Comment: That documentation is actually incorrect. They test for 1.9 to 2.3 and their product manager has told me they technically still support 1.9 even in the latest version. However, they do not officially support 2.3 last time I checked, although I have been using Puppet with 2.3 and it has worked fine. All of their unit and acceptance tests pass for 2.2 and 2.3. Therefore, this is very likely not the real solution to the problem.

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/guides/platforms.html#ruby-versions shows the tested matrix more clearly.

Comment: @MattSchuchard The OP has given too little information to really determine where the problem stems from, but Syck/Psych YAML problems are a problem of Ruby versioning, as the YAML lib was changed with Ruby at some point. Here's the same error with a ticket on Puppet:  https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3796 It seems pretty straightforward to monkey patch this code yourself if needed. The error from the OP is on the exact same line as in the Puppet ticket.

Comment: The link @DominicCleal posted should be referenced instead as it is more accurate and syncs with what Kylo has told me.

Comment: I am getting this error : `ubuntu:~$ rvm install rubygems 1.4.2
system - #downloading rubygems-1.4.2
 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file rubygems-1.4.2.tgz.part: Permission denied
  0  287k    0  1370    0     0   1007      0  0:04:52  0:00:01  0:04:51  4581
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1370)
There was an error(23).
Failed download
There has been an error while trying to fetch rubygems. 
Halting the installation.`

Comment: @Sweety Make a new SO post. That is a different problem not related to Puppet.